# Retrofit - A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, segmentation-fault

I am receiving A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 when using retrofit class to generate an implementation of my service interface.

I believe it is due to a null pointer segment fault in the native libraries. Nothing is thrown so I cannot track it down. The weirdest part is that it doesn't happen on any of my emulators or physical devices (all 6.0) except for my HTC which just happens to be 6.0.1.

Here is my interface:

```
public interface RestApiPerson {
    @GET(QUERY_PERSON)
    Call<PersonSearchResults> getPersonSearchResult(@Query("query") String q);
}
```

Here is the implementation. The crash happens on (Call< PersonSearchResults > call = restApi.getPersonSearchResult(query); )

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(END_POINT_PERSON)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

RestApiPerson restApi = retrofit.create(RestApiPerson.class);
Call<PersonSearchResults> call = restApi.getPersonSearchResult(query);
```

Here's the stack:

```
07-31 12:58:08.492 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3ad75934
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     r0 70fc5774  r1 12d78a00  r2 0025af14  r3 b276c070
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     r4 0025af14  r5 12d78a00  r6 70fc4dc4  r7 715c4a80
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     r8 12c5d190  r9 b8cbad20  sl 71866e80  fp be9a3a9c
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     ip b276c070  sp be9a3a20  lr 73d5b6e5  pc b49ffa68  cpsr 000e0030
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000eaa68  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_imt_conflict_trampoline+7)
07-31 12:58:08.522 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 022b46e3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x2286000)
07-31 12:58:09.812 18310-18310/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
```

Any ideas as to what could potentially be causing the trouble, or how I could go about determining it for myself?

Comment: Have you looked in the tombstone?  There is a lot more detail in those.

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Answer (score -6):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I added this permission to Manifest and it didn't crash anymore.